# Overcoming infinite left recursion in TextX parser

Tags: python, parsing, peg, left-recursion, textx

I am writing a parser for an existing language, using the [TextX](https://pypi.org/project/textX/) Python Library (based on the [Arpeggio](http://www.igordejanovic.net/Arpeggio/stable/) PEG parser)

But when I try to use it to parse a file, I get the exception:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here is a minimal example that raises this exception:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from textx import metamodel_from_str

meta_model_string = "Expr: ( Expr '+' Expr ) | INT ;"
model_string      = "1 + 1"

mm = metamodel_from_str(meta_model_string, debug=True)
m = mm.model_from_str(model_string, debug=True)
```

I tracked it down to Arpeggio's [left recursion issue](https://github.com/igordejanovic/Arpeggio/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#left-recursion-and-recursionerror), where it state that a rule like `A := A B` is unsupported and should be converted to a rule where there is no such recursion.

So my question is: **Is it possible to rewrite the `Expr := Expr '+' Expr` rule above in a way that does not use left recursion?** Note that the real `Expr` rule is much more complicated. A slightly less simplified version of it will be:

```
Expr: '(' Expr ')' | Expr '+' Expr | Expr '*' Expr' | '!' Expr | INT | STRING ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

textX author here. In addition to Paul's excellent answer, there is [expression example](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/blob/master/examples/expression/calc.py) which should provide you a good start.

Top-down parsers in general are not handling left-recursive rules without hacks like this. If your language is going to be complex and heavily expression oriented it might be better to try some bottom-up parser that allows for left recursion and provides declarative priority and associativity specification. If you liked textX then I suggest to take a look at [parglare](https://github.com/igordejanovic/parglare/) which has similar design goals but uses bottom-up parsing technique (specifically LR and GLR). Quick intro example is the exact language you are building.

In [this post](http://www.igordejanovic.net/2017/08/09/parglare-python-parser.html) I blogged about rationale of starting parglare project and differences with textX/Arpeggio.

Answer (score 2):

This is more typically written as:

```
multop: '*' | '/'
addop: '+' | '-'
Factor: INT | STRING | '(' Expr ')' ;
Term: Factor [multop Factor]... ;
Expr: Term [addop Term]... ;
```

Now `Expr` will not directly recurse to itself until first matching a leading '('. You will also get groups that correspond to precedence of operations. (Note that the repetition for `Expr` and `Term` will end up producing groups like `['1', '+', '1', '+', '1']`, when you might have expected `[['1', '+', '1'], '+', '1']` which is what a left-recursive parser will give you.)

Comment: This solution will not accept the original language specification, for example `1 + 1 + 1`  will be rejected.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I can add repetition in the rules, but then the parsed structures look like ['1', '+', '1', '+', '1'] when people typically expect [['1', '+', '1'], '+', '1']. If I change to something like Expr: Term addop Expr, then operations are incorrectly grouped right-associatively, and "1 - 2 + 3" gets incorrectly parsed as ["1", "-", ["2" + "3"]], which would incorrectly evaluate to -4, instead of the desired 2. To address your point, I'll add repetition, with the caveat